# I got this error on w3 schools validator

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Is anyone familiar with the following W3 School Validation error? It is a simple IMG element and it is giving a very funny error on line 43. Column 112. I am stumped.

---

Error Line 43, Column 112: Attribute target not allowed on element img at this point.

```
…/images/logo.png" target="_blank" alt="AltText" title="SomeTitle" />
```

**Attributes for element img:**

Global attributes

alt

src

crossorigin

usemap

ismap

width

height

---

**A Quick Note: "Column 112" is the closing bracket of the `<img/>` syntax.**

Does anyone know what on earth this means? I cannot for the life of me figure this out and it is the only thing stopping my HTML5 code from validating. Just one little error according to W3 and I cannot understand this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a `target` attribute to do in an `<img>` tag? If you want to have a link, then use `<a>`.

Comment: There's no such thing as "w3 schools validator". The W3C provide a validation service. W3Schools (who run a crappy tutorial site that is not affiliated with the W3C at all) link to it.

Comment: The error message “Attribute target not allowed on element img” is rather self-explanatory. The continuation “at this point” might be misleading (it has a somewhat complicated explanation).

Answer (score 2):

You have a `target` attribute on an `img` element. That isn't allowed and doesn't make sense.

Delete `target="_blank"`

---

While you are at it, you should get rid of the `title` attribute (as it doesn't convey any useful information) and [write better alt text](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html).

Comment: Oh duh. I did not even notice that. That is what happens when you write code for hours and hours straight. <IMG>s turn into <A>s and all that lol. Thank you that was the issue. //Smack to face lol...and here is the validation service URL for the skeptics (I meant W3C, as I said hours and hours of writing code =P   http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

Delete you `target="_blank"` from you `img` tag, because, it should be added on your `a` tag. eg:

```
<a href="#" target"_blank"><img src="#" /></a>
```